# iPhone Compiler Fails: No architectures to compile for

Tags: iphone, architecture

I'm trying to implement the [Cocoa plotting framework (Alpha Release 0.1)](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=alpharelease_0.1.zip&can=2&q=&sort=-uploaded) in my iPhone app.

I figured I'd first try to run the sample they provide. I attempted to open and compile the project located in `/Source/examples/CPTestApp-iPhone/`.

It says my base SDK was missing right off of the bat, so I edited the Project settings and the Active Target to use the iOS4 SDK, which I've done before for samples and had work. I'm not sure what to do. I'm running one of the newest Unibody Macbooks, with 10.6.4.

Here is the full error:

```
// - start - //

Check dependencies

[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).

// - end - //
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

**Project Build Settings:**

- Architectures: Standard (armv6 armv7)
- Base SDK: Latest iOS Build Active
- Architectures Only: Checked Valid
- Architectures: armv6 armv7

Delete any sub settings in the Architecture build setting.

**Target Build Settings:**

- Same at project settings.

**Frameworks**
Add the SystemConfiguration.framework to your project. - Not sure why this had any impact.

Clean all targets.
Build for the simulator.

The long explanation for this can be found on our blog: http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/15/fixing-the-missing-required-architecture-arm-in-file-when-developing-for-ipad/

Comment: Thanks, just to be clear, at Architectures: make sure there is no armv7s

Answer (score 42):

I also went to the Build settings for the target(s) that failed and added "i386" to the valid architectures

Answer (score 19):

Adding i386 to the Valid Architectures list worked for me!

Comment: i386 is the architecture for the iPhone simulator

Comment: It is very odd but that fixed it for me too

Answer (score 5):

For me it was that I had to add i386 to the VALID_ARCHS list. Odd, but it fixed my problem for simulator builds.

[See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915953/upgrading-to-xcode-4-error-no-architectures-to-compile-for)

Answer (score 4):

You have selected as active architecture "active arch=i386 (your Mac)" but the project compiles for " VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7 (iPhone Device)", try setting the right arch in the project settings, so it is built for iPhone as it should be.

Comment: The architecture plist entry only has i386 listed, it is not a dropdown like the Base SDK entry, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This project appears to pre-date iOS 4, so you need to open up the `.xcodeproj` file for the Core Plot library itself, too. It probably also has a broken reference to an old iOS Base SDK and may need the architectures updated.

Comment: I was opening the .xcodeproj file. I've not even tried to get this working in my app yet, I'm still trying to run their example. I have changed the SDK, since it said BASE SDK MISSING. I tried 3.2 and 4.0, but still get the error for both.

Answer (score 2):

This happens all the time with old projects migrated to SDK 3.2/4.0.  You have to open the target settings and change everything to SDK 4.0 or 3.2.  You can still have the target OS be 3.0 if you want that.   If it still says "missing SDK" you neglected to change one of those settings to 4.0 or 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

armv6 armv7 , Works for me in valid Architecture .

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all method with "NO SUCCESS"

- Try to run project on you device, if it works on device then it will works fine on simulator too.