# Xcode 4 Needs i386 for iPhone Sim?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I upgraded to Xcode 4.

If I make a new iPad project in Xcode 4, everything works. If I make a project in Xcode 3 and then bring it over to Xcode 4, that works too.

**One of my projects, however, would not compile.** Error was:

```
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).
```

To get it to compile and run in the simulator, I ended up using these settings:

[image: freaky but working settings in XCode 4]

Putting i386 got the project to compile and run ([thanks to this forum thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1094465)), but my other projects do **not** have i386 in the Valid Architectures and still work.

How can I make my project like the others?

**Note:** Yes, I've gone through the project quite carefully (in XCode, not the XML, though) and the non-compiling version did look exactly like its compiling friends.

Comment: also like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915953/upgrading-to-xcode-4-error-no-architectures-to-compile-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the developer forums, I ran across people that edited the .pbxproj file with a text editor, and just added the entries into VALID_ARCHS that way.  It seems to be a problem when XCode4 is handling some older XCode3 projects (although I've not seen that yet).

I checked a current project and this line does not exist, so if you see this problem try removing it from your project.pbxproj file and then restart XCode.

Comment: On one project where I had that issue, I found it was easier to **remove** the VALID_ARCHS line in the project file, instead of trying to edit it.

Doing that, Xcode will revert back to the default options (ie. i386 on Sim, armv6/7 on Device).

Comment: That's what I was saying at the end, I think that is probably the best choice.  I edited the last part of my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Great, I'll try that. You mean "answer" by the way :) Thanks!

Comment: This worked. I don't want to go mucking around and editing your answer, but I just deleted the offending line `VALID_ARCHS = "armv7 i386";` (or whatever your VALID_ARCHS are) in project.pbxproj and... XCode doesn't put it back, but doesn't have problems either.

Answer (score 1):

I had precisely the same issue and wrote a little shell script to programmatically edit the lines where I need to add i386 (I do this in my test harness after every git pull and tag checkout).

Place the following code in a shell script and then run it whenever you need to add i386 to all the VALID_ARCHS= entries:

`sed -i -e 's/.*VALID_ARCHS = armv7;.*/VALID_ARCHS = "armv7 i386";/g' project.pbxproj`

Oh, given the direct simplicity of this script, you need to be in the same directory where the project.pbxproj file is when you run it.

And, as implied, it does a global line replace. It replaces every instance of VALID_ARCHS = armv7; with VALID_ARCHS = "armv7 i386"; and the quotes are necessary or Xcode will throw an error telling you that the project.pbxproj file cannot be parsed.

Comment: sounds good. it's been years, so I have no idea how to evaluate this, but +1 anyway.