# Applicatin is not Compiling for simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just got an application from net. But the problem is it is not compiling for simulator but when i add my provisioning profile and attach device and run it on device it runs fine on it. So I want to know which of the Functionality  will not allow application to  run on simulator. Application is using IN App purchase, device accelerometer.

**Error is**

```
 llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2':
 execvp: No such file or directory

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255
```

Comment: Add some error info from your compiler.

Comment: try running in a different simulator version n see

Comment: please check now. I try different simulator and i also reset them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Last found my solution [on this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915953/upgrading-to-xcode-4-error-no-architectures-to-compile-for)

Very strange. I encountered the same error and both the Debug and Release "Valid Architectures" were set to armv6 and armv7. (The same code compiles fine in Xcode 3.2.) I ended up deleting both settings, then expressly setting them to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) ... which in turn translates to armv6 and armv7 again ... and it compiles just fine now. No i386 needed. Hmm ...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the specific functionality provided by apple in ios that need device are as - IAP(In app purchase),Push Notifications,Accelerometer/Gyroscope ,Image Picking,Camera recording,Calling,Messaging,Open a app from your app,Voice related,Sometime recording also need a device(But i observe it sometime not all the time),Bluetooth data connectivity,App that is using any Game Center functionality need a device,Printer connectivity,Airplayetc.

All these things need a device to run the app you can't check the functionality with the simulator provided for development.I think you got an idea now.

Thanks,

Comment: thanks for your guide. But i think we can run the application on simulator but we cannot test their working on simulator. Like i work on push notification. The device does not register with push but it can run on simulator.

Comment: Is there any functionality that stops application running on simulator?

Comment: Yea you can run but those  feature which using  hardware they will not show the effect of on the simulator.Because simulator is also a programme it is not a hardware alone.And the functionality that stop running on simulator is only the crash but if the framework not support the simulator either it will show the compile time error or it will run but not work. I Think now you should check this query may be it can resolve your problem too.