# iWebDriver - iphone Selenium

Tags: xcode, ipad, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have gotten this to work before so I know its possible, but trying it on a new machine.

I have OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.6, iPad 6.1, and trying to do this:

[Iphonedriver selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver)

I get to the point where I am building the project in Xcode and get this error:

Check dependencies

No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=i386).

My architecture is set to: Standard(armv7,armv7s),
Build Active: Yes,
Valid Architectures: armv7s armv7,

The project is code signed.  Any help is appreciated. I know i missed somehting obvious. Let me know if I left anything out or you need more info.  I have looked at the following SO questions, and other similar ones:

[SO Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549478/iphone-compiler-fails-no-architectures-to-compile-for)
[SO Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915953/upgrading-to-xcode-4-error-no-architectures-to-compile-for)

I was hopeing someone had specific experience with iWebDriver. I will eventually be using this in a GRID 2 configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“armv7 armv7s i386” is what it wanted on all ‘Valid Architectures’ fields (debug and release) for both the project  and target!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in the build settings configurtions, got it fixed with below:

```
Architectures --Standard(armv7,armv7s) - $

Valid Architectures --i386 armv7s
```