# xcode 4.5 dependency issues with iphone 5

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I am trying to build my project to my iphone 5 and I keep getting this warning 
No architectures to compile for `(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7)`
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You get this error becuse your active Architecture is `armv7s` (armv7s is the architecture for iPhone 5's A6 SoC):

> active arch=armv7s

but this architecture is not listed among your valid architectures:

> VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7

Modify the "Valid Architectures" in your project target's "Build Settings" by adding armv7s (you might as well remove armv6 since Xcode 4.5 does not support that any more):

[image]

You might also need to change the "Architectures" property:

[image]

and set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO (so your project is built for all listed architectures including armv7, which older devices, e.g. iPhone 4S, can execute):

[image]

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270184/131183).

Comment: the only thing I had to change was setting the "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO! Thanks

Comment: I guess that by setting it to NO, an armv7 architecture version of your app is built which works on iPhone 5. Glad I could help!