# Xcode - 5.0.2, iOS Check dependencies No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)[iOS Static Code Analysis - Jenkins]

Tags: ios7, jenkins, xcode5, static-code-analysis

I am trying to build my static code analysis configuration for iOS through Jenkins. I am Using     Architecture - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and valid architecture - arm64 armv7 armv7s.

While trying to build the configuration I am receiving the error message

****Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).
** BUILD FAILED ******

Also I tried with armv6 and other architecture , But I am receiving the same error.
I am facing this issue for the code developed for iOS7 and I am using Xcode 5.0.2.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 0):

try to check deployment target -> `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`

Change it to something higher when 3.0 is selected. for your architectures probably iOS 7.0 would be suitable.

I solve this issue with this settings.
Choose project workspace, in xcode choose `General` tab, `Deployment Info` section, change `Deployment Target` to 7.0

You can also change it in `Build Settings` tab in `Deployment` section of your project. Field name is `iOS Deployment Target`

If you are using some versioning system don't forget to commit (and push) changes(like me...)

Comment: Hi , I have tried changing deployment target as you mentioned , but it does not works also the build is getting failed to build even on trying to build from xcode. :-(

Comment: try to paste stacktrace of error you get. I was just guessing. or go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549478/iphone-compiler-fails-no-architectures-to-compile-for. Maybe setting arch i386 will help you too.

Comment: did you set the flag "build active architecture only" to NO in xcode project build settings?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Build Active Architectures Only setting, change Debug to NO

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to build i386 (ARCHS=i386), but you've also told it that only armv7 and armv7s are valid architecures (VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s). Add i386 to the list of valid archs.